# Inserting too much of data in sqlite database

Tags: android, database

I am creating Dictionary Android Application.This app create database of 235883 words that takes to much time to be inserted on database on first time app run.Is there any other solution to make it faster or install direct database file in root folders??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database may be helpful

Comment: Many ways depending on your app ui pattern. I'm not sure what your initial screen will show. If it's not depending on completion of inserting data you can insert them in worker thread. You just have to utilise the time available before he stay using the data. Move to worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can create sqlite database file for your words and put it into assets folder and than you can access it at the time you launch your app.